# json concatenate for request.post python

Tags: python, json

I'm measuring temperature and humidity from a sensor.
I want then to post the measures to a server as json strings.
I'm using a python script.

For optimisation, I want to group the json strings and post them.

My code is like this:

```
current_time = time.localtime()[0:6]
date = dateformat % current_time[0:6]
temp = str(round(temp, 1))
hum = str(round(hum, 1))

lastest_measure = {'UID': uuid, 'date': date, 'temperature': temp, 'humidity': hum}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(lastest_measure), headers=headers)
print r

>>> response 200: Good !
```

But I can't concatenate the `lastest_measure` to a `grouped_measure`.

I tried to concatenate with

```
grouped_measure = dict(group_measure.items() + lastest_measure.items())
```

but it gives me an error:

> "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'item'"

I tried to create a string with all the measure (in the correct format, ie: `[{...},{...}, ...]`
and then use the json.dumps

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(grouped_measure), headers=headers)
```

But I get an error 500 (because the format doesn't inclue the '' between all the values)

So my question is how can I concatenate 2 dictionaries in the right format for the `resquest.post` method ? (is it a method ???)

Thanks in advance !
Cheers,
Mat

Comment: Why not just update the dictionaries in Python using d1.update(d2), then post the request from the json.dumps string?

Comment: i just tried like this lastest_measure.update(grouped_measure), but it only gives me the last measure in grouped_measure. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: The dict.update will override any keys already inside the dictionary, and will update it into the dictionary.

So...
d1 = {k:k**2 for k in range(10)}
d2 = {k:k for k in range(5, 15)}
d1.update(d2)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14}

Comment: If your keys are identical, then the simple answer is you cannot POST the request without iteration in the JSON format. It recognizes specific keys. If you are wondering how to concatenate a series of dictionaries to have a single POST request from multiple dictionaries with different keys, then this is the correct answer. 

However, given the current information you have given, I can't answer beyond that.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. My dictionaries will have the same keys but with different values (ie: temperature changes). I guess I have to iterate in the json format. could you give me an example of iteration ?

Comment: See if that helps. If not, and you are wondering how to make a single POST request, I'm not sure I (or anyone) can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the POST request is expecting a JSON format, which is essentially like a Python dictionary, only it accepts only specific types and requires the keys to be strings.

This means, if you are doing a time series, and have the same keys in a dictionary from many dictionaries, like a Python dictionary, it will override the given values. In short, there is no way to solve the problem using a single POST request for a website that accepts JSON data.

To solve this, you can use iteration.

Here's an arbitrary example, but works for your example:

Step 1: Get the dictionaries (which you already have) and create a Python list from them.

```
# arbitrary case
dicts = []
for num in range(20):
    mydict = {i: i**num for i in range(50)}
    dicts.append(mydict)
```

Now that I have my dictionaries, I can then iterate over them to post the request.

```
import json
# iterate
for mydict in dicts:
    json_string = json.dumps(mydict)
    r = requests.post(url, data=json_string, headers=headers)
```

Now, if you can define the dictionaries and post the requests at the same time, this code will be much more efficient.

Comment: Noted with thanks! but by iterating, I loose the point of my optimisation (lower the POST on the server). Is there another function/method like request.post that accept the format [{...}, {...}, ...] ?

Comment: Not unless the server accepts it. In theory, it could accept a list, but it depends on the server.

You could do json.dumps(dicts), and see if the server accepts the POST request, but no guarantees. Check their API.

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution:

```
data = [ ]
def add_DataSet(field1, field2, field3, field4):
     global data
     data.append({"field1":var1, "filed2":var2, "field3":var3, "field4":var4})
```

then

```
add_DataSet(field1, field2, field3, field4)
```

It works perfect with the

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```